# ASP.Net Web Forms asp:textbox does not render in browser html

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I was hoping that someone would be able to advise why the asp:Textbox on the below aspx page does not render.  When I run the project the html for the text box does not exist?

PatientOtherNames.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PatientOtherNames.aspx.vb" Inherits="PatientOtherNames" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PatientOtherNames</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="test" width="40px" />
  </body>
</html>
```

PatientOtherNames.aspx.vb:

```
Partial Class PatientOtherNames
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you should add a (form) tag with runat ="Server"..

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PatientOtherNames.aspx.vb" Inherits="PatientOtherNames" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PatientOtherNames</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="test" width="40px" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```